# Passing data to php using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to make an ajax call work.

jQuery Code

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/handler/?Action=Variable",
    data: { 
        "Action": "Variable"
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert(xhr);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
if($_GET['Action'] == 'Variable') {echo "done";}
?>
```

`echo "done";` is never being called. I have tried several different ways of doing an Ajax call and none of them are giving me a desired response.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Luke.

**EDIT**
running print_r($_GET); returns

```
Array
(
    [Action] => Variable
    [_] => 1450086386289
)
```

Comment: @Luke_Pring Best way to learn about ajax is doing it in a pure way, only after that is good solution (for me still isn't as time matters) to use frameworks such as JQuery. And also for your future career it will be better to be able to know what happens underneath the hood.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? 404? or other?

Comment: I think the error is in your url because I tried your code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>         
    $.ajax({
        var name='myname'; //exampls this is your variable from ajax
        type:'POST',
        url: '../page.php, //the page where you get the  variable
        data:'name=' + name;
        success:function(data){}
        });
</script>
```

And to GET the variable you pass from AJAX

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name =$_POST['name'];

    }
?>
```

Comment: He already understand that, so no need to tell that thing. Common sense bro.